# Скомпилировать C++ файлы из proto-файлов с помощью CMake

Tags: c++, grpc, google-protobuf

Всем привет!
Пишу на С++ grpc-клиент и хочу чтобы proto-файлов компилировались во время сборки проекта.
Для этого подтягиваю исходники grpc из официального репозитория(https://github.com/grpc/grpc)

В интернете прочитал что нужно использовать функцию `protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp(HEADERS SOURCES path_to_proto_files)`
CMakeLists.txt вот-такой:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(test_grpc LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_RUBY_PLUGIN off)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_PYTHON_PLUGIN off)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_PHP_PLUGIN off)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_OBJECTIVE_C_PLUGIN off)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_NODE_PLUGIN off)
set(gRPC_BUILD_GRPC_CSHARP_PLUGIN off)
set(gRPC_INSTALL ON)
set(gRPC_BUILD_TESTS OFF)
add_subdirectory(grpc)

protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp(HEADERS SOURCES /home/ilyas/avanpost/avanpost-idp/protos)

message(STATUS ${HEADERS})

set(HDRS
    agentcontrol.grpc.pb.h
    wrappers.grpc.pb.h
    timestamp.grpc.pb.h
    agentcontrol.pb.h
    wrappers.pb.h
    timestamp.pb.h
)

set(SRCS
    agentcontrol.grpc.pb.cc
    wrappers.grpc.pb.cc
    timestamp.grpc.pb.cc
    agentcontrol.pb.cc
    wrappers.pb.cc
    timestamp.pb.cc
)

add_executable(test_grpc main.cpp ${HDRS} ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(test_grpc grpc++)
```

`message(STATUS ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})` возвращает пустые строки.

Пробовал сделать как написано в этом вопросе. Но ничего не получилось и зачем тогда функция `protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp(HEADERS SOURCES path_to_proto_files)`?

Как мне сделать так что бы proto-файлы собирались во время сборки проекта и как можно указать место для собранных файлов?

PS:
Оказалось что функция protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp ничего не делает.
На данный момент я с помощью bash-скрипта генерирую файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Функция protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp третим параметром получить список proto файлов, которые она будет обрабатывать. А Вы ей даете каталог. А она так не умеет. Либо давайте с именами

```
protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp(HEADERS SOURCES /home/ilyas/avanpost/avanpost-idp/protos/my.proto)
```

или пусть cmake Вам немного поможет

```
file(GLOB ProtoFiles " /home/ilyas/avanpost/avanpost-idp/protos/*.proto")
protobuf_generate_grpc_cpp(HEADERS SOURCES ${ProtoFiles})
```

И теперь HEADERS и SOURCES будут содержать список сгенерированных файлов, которые можно добавить в нужные бинарники.

> Как мне сделать так что бы proto-файлы собирались во время сборки проекта
> вот так как написано выше. Есть еще десяток неверных способов, их не стоит делать.

> как можно указать место для собранных файлов?

А вот этого Вам не должно хотеться. Файлы, которые нагенерировал протобаф - это такие же файлы, как и *.o или *.pdb. И они все лежат вместе. Я видел несколько случаев, когда пытались использовать "ручной способ" генерации и потом ругались на cmake, на протобаф, на все остальное кроме себя.

Но почему так? все дело в том, что в правильном варианте cmake отслеживает факт изменения прото файлов и корректно пересобирает все зависимости. Если же делать ручками, то либо протобаф всегда перегенерируется (а это увеличение времени компиляции и пересборка того, что не должно было бы пересобираться) либо наоборот - "я тут поменял, а оно не пересобрало!"

P.S. Мне очень не нравится полный путь к протобаф файлам. Там точно должен быть относительный.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Да, вы правы у меня каталог но я пробовал и с полным путем к файлу. Как вы понимаете результата это не дало. Так же попробовал сделать как вы описали flie(GLOB ...) Список файлов я получил но Переменные с хедерами и сорцами все равно остаются пустые. По поводу полного пути - это тестовый проект и чтобы не копировать прото-файлы из основного я прописал полный путь.

Comment: Еще я выяснил что переменная _gRPC_PROTO_GENS_DIR для моих файлов пустая.

Comment: тогда очень очень внимательно смотрите сообщение об ошибках и предупрежениях в консоли.

Comment: может оно просто protoc.exe найти не может

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
add_subdirectory(grpc)

find_program(PROTOC protoc)
find_program(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN grpc_cpp_plugin)
get_filename_component(PROTOS_DIR "proto" ABSOLUTE)
file(GLOB PROTOS ${PROTOS_DIR}/*.proto)

set(GENS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gens)

make_directory(${GENS})

execute_process(COMMAND ${PROTOC}
    -I ${PROTOS_DIR}
    --cpp_out=.
    --grpc_out=.
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN}
    ${PROTOS}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${GENS}
    RESULT_VARIABLE res
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE out
    )

file(GLOB GRPC_PROTOC_GENS "${GENS}/*.cc" "${GENS}/*.h")
```

Но сначала необходимо собрать и установить grpc. Я это делаю из реппозитория на github.

Comment: это самый плохой вариант - в нем как минимум 2 большие проблемы - ручной запуск protoc и glob